# How do you erase all content of a flowdocument

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have created a flowdocument and added numerous paragraphs to it programmically. Now in the I would like to be able to reset the flow document to a blank slate resulting in everything being erased.

I have looked for things like Clear, Reset, RemoveAll, Erase. Is there a method to emptying the document?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Clear the `Blocks` collection of the `FlowDocument`:

```
document.Blocks.Clear();
```

The [How to: Manipulate a FlowDocument through the Blocks Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-manipulate-a-flowdocument-through-the-blocks-property?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) includes this example, as well as other common operations (such as inserting a new paragraph at the beginning, or deleting the last block element).

Answer (score 11):

The following example clears all of the contents ([`Block`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.blocks.aspx) elements) from the [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms601064).

```
flowDoc.Blocks.Clear();
```

See the [How to: Manipulate a FlowDocument through the Blocks Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-manipulate-a-flowdocument-through-the-blocks-property?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for the above example, and [FlowDocument Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) for more examples.